# Resource config error java REST project

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I'm following a tutorial for creating a RESTful java web service. I'm at the point where I have a GET service test method created, however when I try to call it I get the exception:

"SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes"

I googled this error message and read other posts but could not seem to get a working solution from what I read. My web.xml looks like this.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>com.zcservices.rest</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.zcservices.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

My source code class looks like this:

```
package com.zcservices.rest.status;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/v1/status")
class V1_status
{
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String returnTitle()
    {
        return "<p>The webservice is operational</p>";
    }

}
```

My project structure looks like this:

[image]

Full Stack Error: (This occurs when I start the server, yet it will still startup successfully and I will see this error when trying to navigate to the page to exercise the method in the above source code).

```
EVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1359)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:180)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:799)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:491)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:321)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
May 3, 2014 9:00:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Would you mind to add the all the stack error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup looks OK. What strikes me though is that your class has default access. Try making it public:

```
@Path("/v1/status")
public class V1_status
```